# Node JS google cloud messaging topic with prefix got Error: Malformed topic name

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to create backend service using Nodejs to send a notification to all subscribers. I want to make it dynamic, I've read the documentation of how to use the GCM using NodeJS from  [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages) , it says that "The topic name can be optionally prefixed with "/topics/"

Without the prefix, everything works fine, but when I try to add a prefix on it, I got "Error: Malformed topic name"

This is my code right now

```
app.post('/notify', (request, response) => {
// console.log(request.body);
var message = {
    android: {
        ttl: 3600 * 1000, // 1 hour in milliseconds
        priority: 'normal',
        notification: {
            title: request.body.fullname + ' want to join',
            body: 'email: ' + request.body.email + '; tel: ' + request.body.no_telp,
            icon: 'stock_ticker_update',
            color: '#0088aa'
        },
        data: request.body
    },
    topic: '/register/guest'
};

admin.messaging().send(message)
.then((res) => {
    // Response is a message ID string.
    console.log('Successfully sent message:', res);
    response.send("success");
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error sending message:', error);
    response.send('error');
});
```

})

Comment: Thank you, I think the doc is incorrect because some people try following the documentation by adding a prefix, but stuck with the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me that the comment in the first line of sample code on page https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages is incorrect. Under "Defining the Message" there is clearly stated that

> The topic name must not include the /topics/ prefix.

Comment: I think so. I thought the topic is similar to the topic in messaging service like MQTT, that's why I try using the prefix, but the fact is this gives an error. Thank you